# Using loop to scroll through divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've made a single page website, with with each div taking up 100% of the page.

At the moment I have some code that takes the user down the page, one div at a time.

```
$(".box1").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('.box2').offset().top }, 'slow');
});

$(".box2").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('.box3').offset().top}, 'slow');
});

$(".box3").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('.box4').offset().top}, 'slow');
});

$(".box4").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('.box5').offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

Rather than having the user click different divs (box1, box2, etc) each time, can I let the user click the same div (.arrow) every time?

I have attempted this, with the user clicking `.arrow` to go through the loop:

```
var boxes = ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4"];

    for (i = 1; i > boxes.length; i++) {
        $(".arrow")click(function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(boxes[i]).offset().top}, 'slow');
    });

    }
```

This however is unresponsive, and won't scroll at all. Does anyone know what is wrong with this loop?

Comment: As you have it, a click on the arrow will make jQuery try to scroll the page to every box at the same time. (You're also missing a `.`)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would you know how to chain this event?

Comment: function(e) is a closure and therefore `i` will have always the last loop value. Btw. shouldn't the loop be `i < boxes.length` ?

Answer (score 3):

Only have one listener on `.arrow` which has some logic to decide where to go

```
(function enableArrow() {
    var i = 1; // initial box
    $(".arrow").click(function (e) {
        i = i % 5 + 1; // (0 to 4) + 1 => 1 to 5
        $('html, body').animate(
            {scrollTop: $('.box'+i).offset().top},
            'slow'
        );
    });
}());
```

Comment: @downvoter if you don't comment, I can't respond or improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

Paul S. is right. What you attempted to do was assigning multiple click handlers to one `.arrow` element.

Paul S. suggests to define an `i` variable which will be visible to `function (e)` closure and will be modified each time you call the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing like this.Hope this works.

```
var boxes = [".box1", ".box2", ".box3", ".box4"];

    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        $(".arrow")click(function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(boxes[i]).offset().top}, 'slow');
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a click handler per div, why not use event delegation?

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(event) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(event.target).offset().top 
    }, 'slow');
});
```

This way you'll only have a single event handler and the event will carry the div that you clicked on the target.